# Why does my app crash when I try to display my ip usig Inet?

Tags: android

I am trying to display my ip address using Inet but the app crashes when i do so..
do i need to add any permissions so that this does not happen? following is my code

```
try {
            Inet4Address ip= (Inet4Address) Inet4Address.getLocalHost();
            String s=ip.toString();
            TextView text= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
            text.setText(s);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: For debugging purposes, catch generic Exception and look at logcat

Comment: Attach crash log.

Comment: here is the link for the log : https://docs.google.com/document/d/10snr46lcP2zm8H4V9y8RkUN6plW0fK0PYXhvzAHG8wQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: it says android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
how do i handle this?

Comment: how do i handle this? :- remove it from main thread, Use AsyncTask or some other Thread

Comment: yep it worked.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android don't give u permission to run any network related work direct in main thread so you get this Exception :

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

run your code like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                Inet4Address ip= (Inet4Address) Inet4Address.getLocalHost();
                String s=ip.toString();

             TextView text= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
              text.setText(s);
                Log.e("my ip=> ",s+" <<");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();
```

it's just run you code another thread...